# Why does a box, even if it doesn't form a Block Formatting Context (BFC), still adhere to the rules defined by BFC？

Tags: css

Why does a box, even if it doesn't form a Block Formatting Context (BFC), still adhere to the rules defined by BFC, such as vertical arrangement and margin collapsing and so on？

for example: normal div element or body element

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no CSS in your question, only HTML

Comment: @Justinas there is no need for any CSS

Comment: For anyone not understanding the question, please move on. No need to vote to close a question because you lack knowledge to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between **creating** a BFC and **belonging** to a BFC. Your divs are part of the BFC created (by default) by the HTML element so all the rules of BFC apply to them.

> A block formatting context is created by at least one of the following:
>
> - The root element of the document (`<html>`). <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)</sup>

Worth noting that an element can create a BFC but is not part of any  BFC

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div> <!-- I create a BFC but I am part of a flex formating contenxt and not a block formating context -->
```

Comment: @丁少华 it's a flex item, and a flex items create a BFC (check the link in my question to see all the cases)

Comment: I searched online and found that BFC cannot be applied to the grandchild element.
And the W3C has not clearly pointed out the relevant content.
So  I don't agree with this viewpoint ：“the BFC created by HTML will affect the whole page.”

Comment: it's a flex item, and a flex items create a BFC ,    sorry , my question there. I didn't look at your code carefully

Comment: @丁少华 it's not a viewpoint, it's how CSS works. Once you create a Formatting Context (whatever it's nature), it applies to all the elements inside it unless another element create another formatting context. In other words, any element belong to the nearest formatting context created upper in the tree. in your case, body doesn't create any formatting context (same for the divs) so all of them belong to the BFC created by the HTML element.

Comment: @丁少华 form the Spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#normal-flow) : *Boxes in the normal flow belong to a formatting context, which in CSS 2.2 may be table, block or inline. In future levels of CSS, other types of formatting context will be introduced.* --> so any element should belong to a formatting context. It's doesn't need to be the parent element. It can be any ancestor element

Comment: i know 'Boxes in the normal flow belong to a formatting context, which in CSS 2.2 ', This is also the part I'm confused about.   but which leads to another question. 'any element belong to the nearest formatting context '. in your example,The nearest FC to the .box element is the FFC created by the body, but why the .box is not an FFC but a BFC created by HTML

Comment: @丁少华 as I said in my answer, *creating* and *belonging* are two different things. The html play no role here. Box is a flex item so it **belongs** to an FFC and its display is kept block by default so it **creates** a BFC for its future content. And body belongs to the BFC created by html

Comment: @丁少华 simply ask a question like you did with this one so anyone can answer it and also it can benefit for anyone.